# w2k3 AD DC Demotion fails with "no other AD DC for that domain can be contacted"

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

i've a small office with a single `w2k3 sp2 DC`(bad idea, but it is real), now, i want to make a clean install of that pc, so, i got another one, install `w2k3 sp2`, add it to the domain, `dcpromo` and set it to be a `GC`, untill now everything is ok, then tried to `dcpromo` in the `primary DC`, but it fails with

```
The box indicating that this domain controller is the last controller for the
domain mydomain.com is unchecked. However, no other Active Directory domain
controllers for that domain can be contacted.  

Do you wish to proceed anyway?  

If you click Yes, any Active Directory changes that have been made on this
domain controller will be lost.
```

So, i started to move all the roles to the new server as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;255690), when all was ok with the roles, i tried doing the same, but got the same result. Tried moving the `DNS` to the new server, but it doesn't make difference.
Shutdown to the old server, then tried to log into a workstation, but it fails saying the domain is not available, also coudln't add new workstation to the domain, so i have to power on the old server again.
So, if i successfully move all the roles and dns to the new server:
why `dcpromo` give such message in the old server?
why if i shutdown the old server the domain is not available??
if i successfully move all the roles and dns to the new server, and i click yes when `dcpromo` give warning in the old server, will i lose all users, computers, ou, etc.?
am i missing some steps to make this work??

hope you can help me

thanks

Comment: Did you install DNS on the new DC? Is your AD DNS zone AD itegrated? Has the AD DNS zone replicated to the new DC? Are both DC's using themselves and the other DC for DNS? Did you add the new DC/DNS servers to the client DNS settings?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but yes, i already did that, and make no difference

Comment: Should be the `NETLOGON` and `SYSVOL` share be present in each `DC` i have?

Comment: Yes they should. If the SYSVOL share isn't present on the new server it means that something went wrong with DCPROMO or with the replication of the SYSVOL contents. The SYSVOL share is created on the new DC after the contents of SYSVOL on the old DC have replicated successfully. If SYSVOL isn't present it means replication didn't occur at all, broke down or that DCPROMO went south. You should check the Event logs on the old and new DC for clues.

Comment: if i successfully move all the roles and dns to the new server, and i click yes when dcpromo give warning in the old server, will i lose all users, computers, ou, etc.?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: Ok, i check the Event logs, the FIle Replication Service in the old server have a lot with the event id 13568, saying `SYSVOL SHARE` is in `JRNL_WRAP_ERROR`, what about it?

Comment: See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292438

Comment: @joeqwerty, the problem was with the `FIle Replication Service` no working properly, thanks, you helped me a lot. You should elaborate an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i run a `chkdsk` on system partition, some errors got fixed, then i repaired the `OS` and in the description of the event 13568, you can read:

```
Expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. 
Click down the key path: 
   "System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NtFrs\Parameters" 
Double click on the value name 
   "Enable Journal Wrap Automatic Restore" 
and update the value. 

If the value name is not present you may add it with the New->DWORD Value function under 
the Edit Menu item. Type the value name exactly as shown above.
```

after that, i manually restart the `ntfrs` service and wait almost 10-15 min, when checked the Event Logs again, the problem was solved and start replicating successfully.

hope it can help anothers